# how define method and apply to it with some parameters

Tags: ruby, methods

I have some code in which I need to attach a new window page and check if it exists. I need to do this several times. I want to create some class where I can define an algorithm and then just apply to the class with the exact value of title. I wrote the following code:

```
def check_title()
@a
$ie=Watir::IE.attach(:title, @a)
rescue Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException
puts ("could not find browser")
end
end
```

In the required place I paste the code to call the method

```
check=Title.new("Business Partner")
check.check_title()
```

I get this error message -

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Please tell me how I should describe this situation  properly.

Comment: The problem seems to be in your Title class, which you did not provide as a code sample. Please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't know how to create a class in ruby, you should probably buy yourself a book about it, or read one of the gazillion online resources that help you learning ruby...

```
class Title
  def initialize(title)
    @a = title
  end
end
```